# Symfony 6.3 EntityType Field doesn't persist default values on submit

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have three entities as shown in the code below:

```
class MedicalRecord
{

    // ...

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'medicalRecords')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Tooth $tooth = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Intervention::class, inversedBy: 'medicalRecords', cascade: ['persist'])]
  private Collection $interventions;

    // ...

    public function getTooth(): ?Tooth
    {
        return $this->tooth;
    }

    public function setTooth(?Tooth $tooth): self
    {
        $this->tooth = $tooth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Intervention>
     */
    public function getInterventions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->interventions;
    }

    public function addIntervention(Intervention $intervention): self
    {
        if (!$this->interventions->contains($intervention)) {
            $this->interventions->add($intervention);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIntervention(Intervention $intervention): self
    {
        $this->interventions->removeElement($intervention);

        return $this;
    }

}


class Tooth
{
  
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: MedicalRecord::class, mappedBy: 'interventions')]
    private Collection $medicalRecords;

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, MedicalRecord>
     */
    public function getMedicalRecords(): Collection
    {
        return $this->medicalRecords;
    }

    public function addMedicalRecord(MedicalRecord $medicalRecord): self
    {
        if (!$this->medicalRecords->contains($medicalRecord)) {
            $this->medicalRecords->add($medicalRecord);
            $medicalRecord->addIntervention($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMedicalRecord(MedicalRecord $medicalRecord): self
    {
        if ($this->medicalRecords->removeElement($medicalRecord)) {
            $medicalRecord->removeIntervention($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

class Intervention 
{
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: MedicalRecord::class, mappedBy: 'interventions')]
    private Collection $medicalRecords;

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, MedicalRecord>
     */
    public function getMedicalRecords(): Collection
    {
        return $this->medicalRecords;
    }

    public function addMedicalRecord(MedicalRecord $medicalRecord): self
    {
        if (!$this->medicalRecords->contains($medicalRecord)) {
            $this->medicalRecords->add($medicalRecord);
            $medicalRecord->addIntervention($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMedicalRecord(MedicalRecord $medicalRecord): self
    {
        if ($this->medicalRecords->removeElement($medicalRecord)) {
            $medicalRecord->removeIntervention($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Each medical record has a tooth associated and multiple intervention made for each medical record. I made a MedicalRecordType as shown below.

```
class MedicalRecordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {

        $builder
            ->add('interventions', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Intervention::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
            ]);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $formEvent): void {
            $medicalRecord = $formEvent->getData();
            $form = $formEvent->getForm();

            if($medicalRecord->getId()){
                $form
                    ->add('tooth', EntityType::class, [
                        'class' => Tooth::class,
                        'choice_label' => 'name',
                        'required' => true,
                    ])
                ;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

When I create a new MedicalRecord I don't have any problems. Also I add the tooth field on edit only because on new I have some other logic. This is the controller:

```
    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'app_medical_record_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(
        Request $request,
        MedicalRecord $medicalRecord,
        UploaderHelper $uploaderHelper,
        ManagerRegistry $doctrine,
    ): Response
    {

        $patient = $medicalRecord->getAppointment()->getPatient();

        $appointment = $medicalRecord->getAppointment();

        $manager = $doctrine->getManager();

        // i am just displaying the details of the appointment with this
        $appForm = $this->createForm(AppointmentType::class, $appointment);

        $form = $this->createForm(MedicalRecordType::class, $medicalRecord);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $uploadedFiles = $request->files->get('medical_record')['documents'];

            // ... here I have some file saving logic, but it's not important

            $manager->persist($medicalRecord);

            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'updateMedicalRecordSuccess',
                'Success'
            );

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_medical_record_edit', ['id' => $medicalRecord->getId()], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('medical_record/edit.html.twig', [
            'user' => $patient,
            'medical_record' => $medicalRecord,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'formEditVar' => true,
            'appForm' => $appForm->createView(),
        ]);

    }
```

Problem #1 : On edit I get the value of the tooth, but for some reason the field renders null instead. Like nothing is there. However, if I look on the select in HTML, I can see that my default option is selected. However it does not show on the field and on submit it returns null.

(!) Problem #2 : On edit I get the Intervention values that I selected previously when creating the MedicalRecord, but if I save (without making any modifications, except the re-selecting of the tooth, so that it won't return null) all my values are lost. They are erased from the database, as if I selected no intervention. If I try to add new values, the values are persisted to the db, but the ones that I previously selected (that I want to keep) are erased from the database. And I can't figure it out why.

I tried looking at everything, but I have not seen anything wrong. I also tried getting the default values in for the Tooth but then I get problem number 2. All default values of entity type fields are deleted.